# Should I write \begin{quote} ... \end{quote} or \quote ... \endquote?

Tags: environments, description

I find it much easier to type

```
\quote ... \endquote
```

than

```
\begin{quote} ... \end{quote}
```

The same goes for other environments.

I wanted to know if it is "safe" and "sensible" to proceed with the first form, and why, since the results are apparently the same.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}

\begin{description}
  \item[First] Test
  \item[Second] Test
\end{description}

\description 
  \item[First] Test
  \item[Second] Test
\enddescription

\quote This is my quote \endquote 
\enumerate \item \item \item \item \endenumerate 
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'm sure others will give better answers. But this is a bad idea. `\begin` and `\end` include among other things `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`. Environments may well assume this, so things that get changed in the environment will persist after it.

Comment: I might mention that one MUST use \begin{lrbox} ... \end{lrbox} for it to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Always use the `\begin` `\end` syntax, some environments might work using the underlying commands but most will not. It also helps editors to offer syntax highlighting and context sensitive file operations acting on whole environments.

For example here

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}


zzzz

 \quote This is my quote \endquote 

zzzz



\end{document}
```

You will see that `\endquote` does not restore the indentation and the paragraph following is set as part of the quotation not as a standard paragraph.